# HTML5 - Using <hgroup> and <a> problem

Tags: html

If I do this it fails validation

```
<header>
 <hgroup>
  <a href="#">
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <h2>Tagline</h2>
  </a>
 </hgroup>
</header>
```

But if I do this, then Firefox chokes on it

```
<header>
 <a href="#">
  <hgroup>
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <h2>Tagline</h2>
  </hgroup>
 </a>
</header>
```

What is the correct way to have the whole header as a link?

Comment: Could you clarify "chokes on it"?

Comment: hgroup was taken out of the HTML5 specification and is not longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

The latter is correct and seems to work fine in Firefox 4 (Firebug shows correct DOM).